# ASP.NET MVC: Match regex multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc

Regex: `^.*?(?=;)`
Value: `00574/KVMK0224.jpg; 00574/1987432370PHANWHCO00MM.jpg`
Now only matches: `00574/KVMK0224.jpg`
Want: `00574/KVMK0224.jpg` and `00574/1987432370PHANWHCO00MM.jpg`

As I try to explain shortly I have a string with multiple image links, I made it working to get the first link, but now I want all links. I know how to use `regex.Matches` in C# to get multiple matches, the only thing I want to know is what regex to use for this.

What I have to get the first link:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex("^.*?(?=;)");
    Match match = regex.Match(link);
    if (match.Success)
    {
      part.ImageUrl = match.Value;
    }
```

What I made in order to get all links, I think everything is right on this exept of course the regex

```
    Regex regex = new Regex("^.*?(?=;)");
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(link))
    {
      list.Add(match.Value);
    }
```

Probably very simple to do this, but I don't have much experience with regexes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all values are separated by  `;` then you don't need a regular expression. Try this:

```
string imagesString = "....";
string[] images = imagesString.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit: Here you have an alternativ that uses regular expressions and handles white-space:

```
string imagesText = "00574/KVMK0224.jpg; 00574/1987432370PHANWHCO00MM.jpg";
string[] images = Regex.Split(imagesText, @"\s*;\s*");
```

This will work with or without white-space before or after `;`

Comment: Thanks! this works great! Only one last question, all the links after the first will have a space before it, how to get rid of that? (I know how to do it, but maybe there is a smooth way like this?)

Comment: Just use the method `.Trim()` inside the `foreach` loop to get rid of extra white-space. PS: If my answer helped you, please mark it as the the correct answer. I'm glad I could help

Comment: You're welcome. I edited my answer and included an alternative using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up more ways to do this, Learning is never bad :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can try this one  ?

```
[\w/]*?.jpg(?=;)?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I prefer Rui Jarimba's way without using regexes. Really thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: ok no problem, i like the regex's "elegance" :) i learn how to exclude a suffix thanks to you